# Double render error due to multiple request from background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using juggernaut and redis in our application, which sends multiple request to our rails controller because of which double render error is thrown.

We have render :nothing => true in our rails controller.

Any idea to fix this exception?

We are using rails 2.3.

Controller Code:

```
def store_status
  @store = Store.find params[:id]
  @store.update_attributes(:stauts => 1)
  render :nothing => true
end
```

Edit:

Sorry the reason for this double render error is because some exception is raised after the call to render :nothing => true which is catched in my application controller.
The rescue exception block contains another render so the double render error was raised.
Any idea to find if there is already a render and then render in the rescue block?

Comment: Sending multiple requests should _not_ throw a double render error, as each request should get it's own complete response.  What does your action look like?

Comment: In the action We just store some data in database and call render :nothing => true.

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate on that - there's not much to go on so far

Comment: Can you show controller code?

Comment: Updated the question with relevant code.

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry the reason for this double render error is because some exception is raised after the call to render :nothing => true which is catched in my application controller.
The rescue exception block contains another render so the double render error was raised.
Any idea to find if there is already a render and then render in the rescue block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry the reason for this double render error is because some exception is raised after the call to render :nothing => true which is catched in my application controller.
The rescue exception block contains another render so the double render error was raised.
Any idea to find if there is already a render and then render in the rescue block?

Solution:

use erase_results to clear your previous render or redirect before rendering in the resuce method

Answer (score 0):

try `return render :nothing => true`

Comment: Sorry the reason for this double render error is because some exception is raised after the call to render :nothing => true which is catched in my application controller.
The rescue exception block contains another render so the double render error was raised.
Any idea to find if there is already a render and then render in the rescue block?